# Spectral Analysis - converting a specific frequency into the time domain

Tags: time-series, signal-processing, fft

I have time series data that I want to decompose into its intrinsic frequencies. After running FFT on the series, I am left with a periodogram with the main frequencies.

Is there any way to extract a specific frequency and convert it back into the original time-domain?

For example, if I find a 7-day frequency, I can understand that this is a weekly cycle, however, is there any way to understand on what day the peaks occur?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Use a complex FFT instead of a scalar periodogram.  The magnitude of a complex FFT shows the peaks, but the complex inverse (complex IFFT) of a single complex FFT peak (might be more than one sample in width) will retain the phase information and result in the proper time relationship of a particular cyclic component to the original time series.

Note: The input to the complex IFFT needs to retain conjugate symmetry for the result to be real instead of complex (except for rounding/quantization noise).